# Magento : url structure

Tags: magento2, module, magento-1, url

Please explain what is the meaning of this statement in Magento 
`$this->_redirect('*/*/');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That will redirect to the current module, current controller and index action within that controller.  '*' basically means 'current' with redirection.

Comment: @PankajR. If this solved your problem please mark it as accepted.